# How can I connect the SQL in C# and using the command of Adapter

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\bbbde\Database2.mdb");
    cnn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\bbbde\Database2.mdb";
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select count(*) Form nameList where  name='" + textBox1.Text + "'and password ='" + textBox2 + "'", cnn);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Show();
    }
```

and here is the error I get:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'count(*) Form nameList where  name=''and password ='System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: ''.'

Comment: It should be `textBox2.Text` in the query. By the way this code is prone to sql injection. You should use parameterized command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33688556/2946329

Comment: what is `Form`? Use  `FROM`

`"select count(*) FROM nameList where  name='"` and use parameters as Chetan already mentioned

Comment: thanks .But the problem now is  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'

Answer (score 1):

you are missing

1. Form its wrong right is **FROM**
2. textBox2 here you are assigning a textBox2 object as password, not its text so it should be **textBox2.Text**

**Corrected code**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\bbbde\Database2.mdb");
    cnn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\bbbde\Database2.mdb";
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select count(*) FROM nameList where  name='" + textBox1.Text + "'and password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", cnn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {

        this.Hide();
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

well,i have to rewrite my code with a new methon ,It is using oleDbDataAdapter。
the problems is i want to creat a login from with c# and using the oleDbDataAdapter to connect the access.i dont know how to use select function to the login button ,how to write it?

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {

        oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText =

                 "select * from book where usersname = '" + textBox1.Text + "' ";


        oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText =

                 "select * from book where password = '" + textBox2.Text + "' ";


        dataSet11.Clear();

        oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet11);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")         

        {


            this.Hide();

            Form2 frm = new Form2();
```

frm.Show();

```
        }

    else

        {
```

MessageBox.Show("please check youe usersname and password");

```
        }

    }
```